# how to refresh folder in python

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

How to refresh the folder in python because I capture the new images from the Pi camera and I want to read the image using PIL Image from that folder. I use glob to read the image from the folder. But it can read on the image before the new images created. I cannot read the new images created after that code run. How to refresh the folder to read the images.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail, ideally some sample code? It's hard to understand why you couldn't just run glob again to detect the new files.

Comment: Thank you. I have already solved this probelm. I use watchdog to detect the new incoming file then I can read the file.